# Footer won't stay in the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, position, footer

I'm am having some trouble, trying to get my footer to stay at the bottom of my page and the only tutorials I can find has a fixed position, which I dont want it to. I just want the footer to stay at the bottom of the page, so if the copyright line is at 1000px down on the page, that is where the footer will be. Right now it is at the top of the page, right under the header which it isn't supposed to.

My code (html):

```
<body>
    <div id="footer">

            <div class="CopyrightLine">
            &copy; Copyright
            </div>

        </div>
</body>
```

My code (css):

```
    #footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000000;
    float: left;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

EDIT:

I have now changed the code to look like this.

```
    #footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000000;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.CopyrightLine{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -70px; /*half the image width*/
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

But it still wont work, even though I make alot of text on top, to try and make it move.

Comment: Add `position:absolute;` then only `bottom:0;` work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I fixed it my self, I will leave the code here if anyone has the same problem.

html part:

```
<body>

        <div id="header">

        </div>

        <div id="container">

        <div id="content">

        </div>

        </div>

        <div id="footer">

        </div>


</body>
```

css part:

```
body {
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

body > #container {
    height: auto; 
    min-height: 100%;
}

html {
    height:100%;
}   

#footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000000;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-top: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}

#content{
    padding-bottom: 200px;
}

#container{
    height:100%;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000000;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I've come with some suggestions to make your code better: http://jsfiddle.net/s4t11q3L/1/
1) HTML5 tags (`<header>`, `<footer>`, `<main>` instead of `<div>`.
2) Removing `float`s, `clear`s and `position: relative` as they do not have an effect on at least what you posted here.
3) Cleaning up unnecessary code that you don't need.
4) Adding example content instead of margin on the footer. You don't want the `margin-top: 1000px` later when you have content there. The footer will automatically go down to the bottom when there is content.

Comment: If you found it helpful, please upvote my answer further up on the page, as it was the one closest to your final solution :) thanks

Answer (score 5):

You could use absolute position on the footer with some tricks as follows.

http://jsfiddle.net/a5q2u4bv/1/

```css
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 150px;
}
footer {
    background: silver;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <main>main</main>
    <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

1: Why do you have it floated? `float: left` can be easily removed if it doesn't have any purpose. Floating could also cause problems with positioning, and be the reason that it doesn't work.

2: The `bottom` property only works when the element is something other than `position: static`. If it's not specified, it's `position: static` by default. `position: absolute` is probably what you want.

3: Does your site have a vertical scrollbar yet (so much content so that you could scroll it)? If you add more content to the site so that there becomes a scrollbar on the site and your footer code is the farthest down in the HTML, it will probably be at the bottom without specifying anything more. Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/j1hhc98v/2/

Comment: I have now remove float and added the absolute position, but it stil stays in the middle even though i write alot of stuf on top, to make it go down.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sticky footer site. This is probably what you are looking for.

This is the first one I saw and still use. http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

However CSS tricks has a good one too. Very similar but uses the pseudo :after instead of a div.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: In general, you should include a summary of all links, especially considering that the first link is now (as of 2017-4-23) broken.