# Getting rid of vertical scrollbar that comes with sticky footer

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I'm currently working on a web app that requires the footer to be at the bottom. I was able to get the footer to the bottom, but on my screen, I have to scroll down to see the footer despite the content not taking up the whole page.

I have the following CSS code for the sticky footer:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  overflow: none;
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -2em; /* Height of footer */
 }

.push {
  height: 2em;
} 

.primary-footer {
   width: 100%;

}
.primary-footer .copyright {
  height: 2em;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  clear: both;
}
```

The layout of the project can be seen at: https://jsfiddle.net/7m6Lqmww/

Based off of jsfiddle, it appears to work fine on smaller screens, but on bigger screens, a vertical bar appears.

Comment: You can try this technique, I think it's smarter - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28920634/483779

Comment: Wait, are you trying to get the footer to always be at the bottom of the screen? Like even when you scroll down the footer will be "stuck" on the bottom of your display? Like this http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/bodyfix.html were the reserved things are stuck to the bottom when you scroll?

Comment: No, I just need it to not display a scrollbar when it's not necessary which I think @sdcr solution did the trick for my case.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons your current code doesn't work:

1. You incorrectly accommodate the size of your footer. It has a padding which add's to it's total size. You could change that with a different box-sizing option:

   .primary-footer .copyright {
       box-sizing: border-box;
   }

But I think it would be better to just use an em value for padding-top and add that into your factoring for the total footer height.

2. You don't account for the height of the header. You are trying to shift the footer down by having an element the size of the whole page above it, but that element is already pushed down by the header. You will have to set the height value for it.

Which leaves us with this:

```
.primary-footer .copyright {
  height: 2em;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-top: .25em; /* change */
  clear: both;
}
#container {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* add */
  overflow: none;
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-top: 2em; /* add */
  margin: -2em auto -2.25em; /* change */
}

header {
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding: .25em 0;
}
```

Adding the padding and margin tops shifts the container up so that it is flush with the top of the page while keeping its contents visible. Box-sizing prevents additional height from being added to the container by the padding.

NOTE: I've changed the padding values from percentages to pixels in the header and footer. Padding percentages are based on width which would make it impossible to calculate the total size of the elements.

Comment: I still get the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Do you know the height of your header? It's not set in your fiddle but I think I need it for this to work.

Comment: My current height is set at 15%, although this value may change later on.